# Refreshing page gives "404 page not found", deploy react build in subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to upload react application with multi routes build file on DigitalOcean server in subdirectory (/admin).
When we refresh page. it shows 404 page not found.   Example URL:`http://example.com/admin/home`

Please check below `.htaccess` file commands

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /admin/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  RewriteRule ./index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

not families with react build upload.

Comment: What is the sample link you are hitting? You can mention it like: `http://localhost:80/abc_test` etc form.

Comment: Did you create the project with **Create React App**? And if you did, did you follow the instructions on how to deploy to a non-root path found [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths)?

Comment: Where is your `index.html` file present? Is it present inside admin folder?

Comment: yes @RavinderSingh13, index.html file is inside the admin folder

Comment: @manishhedau, Try changing **form** `RewriteRule ./index.html [L]` **To** `RewriteRule ^ admin/index.html [L]` once and see how it goes? Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I tried changing the rule but not working, <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /admin/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  RewriteRule ^admin/index.html [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @manishhedau, ok put a dummy line like `------` in your .htsccess file and then hit any url if you get 500 internal error then it means tour htaccess is enabled else you need to enable it. Check it once and let us know how it goes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I have put just only `------------` in .htacess file but i am getting not found message. and initial `/admin` URL page is loading properly actually but other URL like /admin/dashboard gives page not found message when we relaod.

Comment: @manishhedau, then we gotcha, Please do **enable** your htaccess file.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, inital `/admin` page load properly but when we hit `/admin/user`  URL then page not found message get show in browser.

Comment: @manishhedau, see as mentioned in previous comment, if putting a DUMMY line `-------` is NOT giving you 500 internal error then .htaccess is NOT enabled.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, i will check .htaccess is enable or not and let you know.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: @MrWhite inside the /admin directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `.htaccess` and `index.html` files are inside the `/admin` subdirectory then the `.htaccess` file should look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Note there are 3 arguments in the last rule, *space* separated
(ie. `RewriteRule<space>.<space>index.html<space>[L]`):

- `.` - a single dot. The *pattern*. Matches everything except the document root.
- `index.html` - the *substitution* string. No slash prefix.
- `[L]` - flags. `L` indicates the last rule and stops the current round of processing.

Note also that I've removed the `RewriteBase` directive altogether. And removed the slash prefix from the start of the *substitution* string. The `<IfModule>` wrapper should also be removed.

> ```
> RewriteRule ./index.html [L]
> ```

The syntax of your original rule (above) was incorrect as you appear to have either missed the first argument entirely or combined both arguments into one.

---

*From comments...*

> Try changing form `RewriteRule ./index.html [L]` To `RewriteRule ^ admin/index.html [L]`
> @RavinderSingh13

Since the `RewriteBase` directive is still present (and the `.htaccess` file is inside the `/admin` directory anyway) this would have resulted in an erroneous rewrite to `/admin/admin/index.html` (a 404).

> `RewriteRule ^admin/index.html [L]`
> @manish hedau

However, you had omitted the *space* after the first argument, so this would not have done anything (the rule would not have matched).

> I have put just only ------------ in .htacess file but i am getting not found message.
> i will check .htaccess is enable or not and let you know.

Is `.htaccess` enabled? Do you have access to the server config?

Bear in mind that if you are using LiteSpeed (not Apache) then typing `-----` at the top of the file will be silently ignored - no error.